# NHibernate; basics of Bi-directional 1:m, m:m and List/IList

Tags: c#, .net, database, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

My understanding of List vs IList and other collections is quite limited, so I need to ask:

[NHibernate documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional) says:

*Please note that NHibernate does not support bidirectional one-to-many associations with an indexed collection (list, map or array) as the "many" end, you have to use a set or bag mapping.*

Does the implementation of the class below respect this limitation? In other words; Does it suffice to declare the property as an IList while still being initialized as a concrete List?  Or I need to use a different type of collection?

And can I use a specific implementation of any container, or does it have to be an interface?

Example is from the [FluentNHibernate tutorial](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started), so I assume it would be ok, but I would like to understand it more in-depth than just to accept it on that basis.

```
public class Store
{
  public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Employee> Staff { get; set; }

  public Store()
  {
    Products = new List<Product>();
    Staff = new List<Employee>();
  }

  public virtual void AddProduct(Product product)
  {
    product.StoresStockedIn.Add(this);
    Products.Add(product);
  }

  public virtual void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
  {
    employee.Store = this;
    Staff.Add(employee);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you map it as `bag`, that's fine.

Keep in mind that NHibernate will replace your `List` with a `PersistentGenericBag` when persisting/loading, so always program to the interface.

Comment: "map it as bag": Does this mean I need to add something to the mapping? Say it is:  HasMany(x => x.Staff).Cascade.All();  I need to modify this? Or probably I don't understand the definition of "bag"..

Comment: I don't know what's the default for Fluent; you should dump the XML to check, since Fluent authors had the "great" idea of renaming concepts and hiding important details from NH. If the default for an IList is not bag, you should probably add something like `.AsBag()`

Comment: @bretddog, you don't need to do anything special it will map it as a bag by default if your property is an IList.